# Preciso acessar o sdados dessa lista e salvar em um arquivo txt linha por linha

Tags: python-2.7

```
From matricula import Aluno
class repasse_matricula(Aluno):
    def __init__(self):
        arq = open('Alunos Matriculados.txt', 'r')
        self.alunos_matriculados = []
        for k in arq:
            if k == 1:
                nome = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 2:
                cpf = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 3:
                rg = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 4:
                contato = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 5:
                rua = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 6:
                numero = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 7:
                cep = self.alunos_matriculadosk
            elif k == 8:
                bairro = self.alunos_matriculados[k]
            elif k == 9:
                cidade = self.alunos_matriculados[k]

            self.alunos_matriculados.append(k)
        print self.alunos_matriculados
        arq.close()
    def salvar_matricula(self):
        for k in self.alunos_matriculados:
            arquivo = open ('Alunos Matriculados.txt', 'w')
            arquivo.writelines(self.alunos_matriculados[k].nome+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].cpf+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].rg+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].contato+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].rua+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].numero+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].bairro+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].cep+'\n')
            arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].cidade+'\n')
            arquivo.close()
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: eu consigo acessar o arquivo a salvar os dados na lista, mas quando vou ler a lista e salvar novamente no arquivo, ou não salva nada, ou apresenta erro

Comment: Mas a função `salvar_matricula(self)` está sendo mesmo chamada? Onde? Porque além do construtor, outros métodos da classe não são chamados automaticamente.

Comment: Eu chamo no construtor, para fazer um teste

Comment: aparece esse erro '  File "D:/Projeto Final/repositorio alunos2.py", line 32, in salvar_matricula
    arquivo.write(self.alunos_matriculados[k].nome+'\n')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'